# Organize Android src folder in subfolders (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, project, subdirectory

Sorry for the noob question but I am pretty new to the Android SDK/Eclipse environment

The application I am developing is getting pretty big with several classes. I would like to organize it better, having folders for views, models, dialogs ect...

How can I create a subfolder of the src folder? If I right click on the src folder I do not have that option...Should I create a new package?

I tried to add a new src folders, but that goes to the same level of the main src folder with "default package" path and Eclipse does not see my files there...

What is the best way to have a folder structure for all my classes in a project?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

right click to folder, select new package

Comment: is it added automatically to the build path?

Comment: It works, but I get duplicated entries? I get both a subfolder and a folder on the same level of "src", with the same classes inside?

Comment: try to rename your package to other name. After that you will have: main folder: com.a , sub: com.a.b

Comment: after you have created your packages, just Gliss classes that you want to put in each folder , for example, you will drag and drop your classes methods and put them on the folder com.yourapplication.model , etc

Comment: @Houcine yes, but I get duplicates. I get "com.mycompany.myapp.mysubfolder" twice, one as a subfolder of "com.mycompany.myapp" (which is correct), one as a parallel folder...Should I live with that?

Comment: yeah , it's not twice , if your create for example two packages with these names : com.yourcompany.yourapp.subfolder1 and com.yourcompany.yourapp.subfolder2 , you will have two subfolders like this  : 
src/com/yourcompany/yourapp/subfolder1/ and 
src/com/yourcompany/yourapp/subfolder2/

and then put your classes on the package you want

Comment: I hit refresh and the duplicates disappeared! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

**right click on the src folder => New => Package =>** rename your package for example to :

```
com.yourapplication.model
com.yourapplication.view
com.yourapplication.utils
com.yourapplication.adapters
```

etc

Comment: Note that any class constructors that are not explicitly public will give you a "constructor is not visible" error after you move them.

Answer (score 2):

Its because your using package explorer.  Switch to Navigator (window-->show view ---> other -------> Navigator)

now you can see the project as folders instead of packages.

Answer (score 1):

You must
Right click on "youfolder" -> "Build path" -> "add to build path" or "user as source folder"